# Best way to implement status check using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've got to implement a scenario where I have to listen to a certain request status from server side. What is the best way to implement this feature without using an ajax request every pre defined time period.

What I think of implementing is an ajax request to the web resource every 5 seconds to poll the status of the server until the status becomes true. If then, I will end the polling sequence and shift into a different screen. Is this the optimum way of doing such a thing. or else...

What is the most feasible way to implement such a feature.

Comment: I think push notifications would work better in a case like this. Last time I used SignalR. If you like low level stuffs better, you can simply use websokets, but is easier to use a framework what relies on it.

Comment: Without use AJAX is by server-side codifying. But you need to reload the page to update values. I think you search of an AJAX solution even if you think the opposite

Comment: Or you could set up websockets on your server and push messages up that way?

Comment: I'm more of thinking of a solution which I can implement from the front end side! would help that way cus I have limited access to the backend!

Comment: That won't leave you much choice. Now suddenly AJAX every 5 seconds sound good...

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude I think the OP meant "without frequent AJAX requests", not "without AJAX at all"

Comment: So the conclusion is to send Ajax requests every 5 seconds?

Comment: The question seems to be too-broad since the answer depends on what you have on server side. However I would advise to start with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)

Comment: The server is developed using java and I'm not maintaining or have access to the code so which make my problem worse kinda!

Answer (score 0):

I think push notifications would work better in a case like this.

Last time I used [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr).
If you like low level stuff better, you can simply use [websokets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), but is easier to use a framework what relies on it.

**Based on your comment:**

> I'm more of thinking of a solution which I can implement from the
>   front end side! would help that way cus I have limited access to the
>   backend!

the possible techniques are getting very small, and doing a possibly minimal AJAX check request every x seconds sounds reasonable.
I cannot come up with other simple front-end only solution.

That of course doesn't mean there isn't a better solution out there.